# 'Insert three vertical aligning texts by using the Text-environment'

Tags: vertical-alignment, text-mode

**The three texts are**

(1). (The coefficients of x+1)

(2). (The coefficients of (x+2)^{2})

(3). (The coefficients of (x+1)^{3})

[image]

**NOTE**:-
The alignment of the three texts must look something like this:-

[image]

```
   \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
   \usepackage{array,booktabs}
   \newcommand*{\Ph}{\hphantom{)}}%

   \begin{document}
   Expand $(x+1)^{2}$, $(x+1)^{2}$, $(x+1)^{3}$,\dots, $(x+1)^{n}$. Proceeded by successive distribution, using detached coefficients.\\\\
   \noindent
   $\begin{array}{@{} >{{}}r *{12}{ @{}>{{}}r<{{}}@{} } }
   & 1 & + & 1 & \\
   \times \\
   & 1 & + & 1 \\
   \midrule
   & 1 & + & 1 \\
   &   & + & 1 & + & 1\\
   \midrule
   & 1 & + & 2 & + & 1 \\
   & 1 & + & 1 \\
  \midrule
   & 1 & + & 2 & + & 1 \\
   &   & + & 1 & + & 2 & + & 1\\
   \midrule
   & 1 & + & 3 & + & 3 & + & 1 \\ 
  \end{array}$
  \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an extra column and place the text in that, then use `\cmidrule` instead of `\midrule` to draw the lines across just the first columns.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,amsmath}
\newcommand*{\Ph}{\hphantom{)}}%

\begin{document}
Expand $(x+1)^{2}$, $(x+1)^{2}$, $(x+1)^{3}$,\dots, $(x+1)^{n}$. Proceeded by successive distribution, using detached coefficients.\\\\
\noindent
$\begin{array}{@{} >{{}}r *{7}{ @{}>{{}}r<{{}}@{} } @{}>{\quad}l }
   & 1 & + & 1 & & & && \text{(The coefficients of  $x+1$)}\\
   \times \\
   & 1 & + & 1 \\
   \cmidrule{1-8}
   & 1 & + & 1 \\
   &   & + & 1 & + & 1\\
   \cmidrule{1-8}
   & 1 & + & 2 & + & 1 &&& \text{(The coefficients of  $(x+1)^2$)}\\
   & 1 & + & 1 \\
   \cmidrule{1-8}
   & 1 & + & 2 & + & 1 \\
   &   & + & 1 & + & 2 & + & 1\\
   \cmidrule{1-8}
   & 1 & + & 3 & + & 3 & + & 1 & \text{(The coefficients of  $(x+1)^3$)}\\ 
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I did not know about the `\cmidrule` environment. I tried different ways which did not work. Thank you very much for making the improvements!